# NX typescript library - package.json wrong "main" value - index.ts instead of index.js

Tags: typescript, package.json, nomachine-nx

I've created an NX workspace using

```
npx create-nx-workspace --name libtest --preset angular --style scss --appName demo --nxCloud false
code libtest
```

Then I created a TypeScript library using

```
nx add @nrwl/node
nx generate @nrwl/js:library --name=example-qr-code --buildable --publishable --import-path @example/qr-code
```

This library contains an example function by default:

```
export function exampleQrCode(): string {
  return 'example-qr-code';
}
```

First, to be sure, update the workspace to the latest NX again:

```
nx migrate latest
```

Open the package.json and restore the `^` and `~`.

Run

```
npm update
npx nx migrate --run-migrations
```

Now I can use this function in my application

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { exampleQrCode } from '@example/qr-code';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.title = exampleQrCode();
  }

  title = 'demo';
}
```

Obviously, nothing yet happens with the title. So I opened the `app.component.html` and replaced everyting with

```
{{ title }}
```

And start the application:

```
npm start -- --open
```

There's still some scripts missing from the root `package.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "nx",
    "nx": "nx",
    "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main",
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  ...
}
```

Now you can build the entire workspace (or more precisely, main project with dependencies) using

```
npm run nx run-many -- --target=build --projects=demo --configuration=production
```

After this you can see the build result in the `dist` folder:

[image: distfiles are inside another src folder]

I'm able to run the project from the NX workspace successfully, but I'm unable to create a new angular project and use this library in it.

> ./node_modules/@example/ng-qr-code/fesm2020/example-ng-qr-code.mjs:6:0-53 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@example/qr-code' in 'C:\repos\qrtest\node_modules@example\ng-qr-code\fesm2020'

However, when I open the `package.json` file from the `node_modules/@example/qr-code` and change from

```
{
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  ...
}
```

to

```
{
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  ...
}
```

manually, then everything starts working.

Did anyone else experience this? How can I have NX generate a `package.json` with the `main` field set to a **js** file?

Repository is hosted [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah never mind... Just changing the `main` field in the source `package.json` to `./src/index.js` does the trick.

The file doesn't really have to exist at build time...